# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer values are not getting resolved for beans in imported context

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configured in my web application's Spring context which in turn imports few other contexts which are in JARs that expect certain properties to be configured. But for some reason the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer values ware not available to them and I get error on start up:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegalcharacter in path at index 1: ${dax.svc1.endpoint}

Here is what my application context looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
     xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation=" 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd    
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd    
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" name="mhpVariables">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:appconfig.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <import resource="classpath:com.test.svc1/childContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:com.test.svc2/child2Context.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Child context is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
     xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
    <!-- connection info -->
    <bean class="com.test.java.framework.dataaccess.ServiceConnectionInfo" id="ConnectionInfo">
        <property name="defaultUri" value="${dax.svc1.endpoint}"/>
        <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="500"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerHost" value="50"/>
        <property name="readTimeout" value="3000"/>
        <property name="ConnectionTimeout" value="1000"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I verified the property file is on the classpath and has the property `dax.svc1.endpoint`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Which version of Spring are you working with - can you please confirm this, you have references to 2.0 schema at places.

Comment: Still does not work in spring 4.3 and java config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a placeholder bean inside each of the imports; that's the only way I could get it to work as I have a similar setup to what you describe. I also removed the id from the bean to prevent any id conflicts in the container.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="WEB-INF/myconfig.properties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you have all the xml directives... check the encoding of your properties file (also your XML)

Comment: what do you mean by xml dorectives ? encoding in my xml files is utf-8 not sure about the property file encoding though